# Is there a way to see the programs stdout and stderr in delve debugger for golang?

Tags: go, delve

I'd like to be able to see the stdout and stderr when using delve to debug go programs. Is this possible? How would I do this?

Comment: For my own interest could you post link to delve as I have not heard of it?

Comment: https://github.com/derekparker/delve

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to do anything.

Delve by default prints the stdout and stderr to its console. 
I have tried this in MacOS ElCapitan delve version 0.11.0-alpha

Have a main.go in the right subdir in your GOPATH

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "os"

func main() {
    fmt.Fprintf(os.Stderr, "Writing something to stderr\n")
    fmt.Fprintf(os.Stdout, "Writing something to stdout\n")
}
```

Then run the delve in the same dir as the main.go

```
$ dlv debug
Type 'help' for list of commands.
(dlv) restart
Process restarted with PID 70964
(dlv) c
Writing something to stderr
Writing something to stdout
Process 70964 has exited with status 0
(dlv)
```